# Why couldn't Integer type convert to Double type automatically in Java8 stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

There is something wrong if there is an Integer type value "4" in the code, if change "4" to "4.0", It's ok. I thought Integer type can convert to Double type automatically, but it didn't. So what's wrong with my previous code?

If there is an Integer type "4" in the below code, error occurs as below:

> *Incompatible types: Number & Comparable> is not convertible to double.*

```
double minValue   = Stream.of(4, 0.1).reduce(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double::min);
```

BUT If I change "4" to Double type "4.0", it works well.

```
double minValue   = Stream.of(4.0, 0.1).reduce(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double::min);
```

Comment: because the **type inferred** for the first line of code is `<Number & Comparable...>`  which is not deterministically a `Double`.

Comment: `Stream.of(4, 0.1)` did not know that you wanted doubles, so it did not try to convert the integer. Maybe `Stream.of<Double>(4, 0.1)` works.

Comment: @Thilo If I remember correctly, the type parameter should be written *in front* of the method name: `Stream.<Double>of(4, 0.1)`. This is sometimes referred to as a *type witness*.

Comment: @Thilo it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because there is no autoboxing convert defined between `int` and `Double`.

From [JLS 5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7):

> Specifically, the following nine conversions are called the boxing conversions:
>
> - From type boolean to type Boolean
> - From type byte to type Byte
> - From type short to type Short
> - From type char to type Character
> - From type int to type Integer
> - From type long to type Long
> - From type float to type Float
> - From type double to type Double
> - From the null type to the null type

As such, `1` is boxed to `Integer`, and your stream's inferred type is something which matches both the boxed types `Integer` and `Double`: `Number & Comparable<?>`. (Technically, this is the *least upper bound* of the types)

Instead, you either need to explicitly box the `int` yourself (`Double.valueOf(1)`), or cast it to a `double` (`(double) 1`), or specify it as a double literal (`1.0`).

Comment: Or use `DoubleStream.of(…)` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. For stream you entered a number which is an integer. So it is showing error when you trying to get it as double.

However in 2nd example you gave double as input so output is possible without any error.

See one array and stream explanation below in bit complex structure (2D array)

```
double[][] doubleArray = Arrays.stream(intArray)
                               .map(arr -> Stream.of(arr).mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue).toArray())
                               .toArray(double[][]::new);
```

This can be decomposed as follows:

First you use `Arrays.stream` to create a `Stream<Number[]>`. Then for each `Number[]`, you create a `Stream<Number>`, and use `mapToDouble` to get `DoubleStream` and then `toArray()` to get the `double[]` array.

The final `toArray` call transforms this `Stream<double[]>` into a `double[][]` array.

Now for your code.

```
    DoubleStream stream1 =     Stream.of(4, 0.1).mapToDouble(num -> (doub b le)num);
    stream1.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answered from mobile. Sorry for not structured answer but I think it helps.